# XAML Inheritance

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, inheritance

I have a very odd problem.

I have a BaseClass that is just a VB class that inherits UserControl, there is no XAML.

Then I created a Child1Class that inherited BaseClass. In the Child1Class XAML I have this:

```
<Base:BaseClass x:Class="Child1Class" ......
                xmlns:Base="clr-namespace:InheritaceProject">
```

This is where the weird part comes in. I did this in 2 projects, in the first the XAML designer displayed properly but in the 2nd project, it has the blue underline under Base:BaseClass, the error is "Cannot create an instance of BaseClass".

But in both projects, it compiles and runs properly.

The only difference in the 2 projects is that in the 2nd project I have the BaseClass and Child1Class in a folder. Would the problem be because of that? But when I shift the 1st project files into a folder, it still doesn't have that blue line.

Does any know what the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to inherit XAML based UIs. XAML has its own mechanisms to provide UI composition and reuse. Please edit your question and clarify `why` you're trying to do this. Chances are there is a much better approach that does not involve UI element inheritance.

Comment: I would open it up in Blend and see if you get the same problem.  The Visual Studio designer can't display XAML very well.

Comment: @HighCore: I'm not trying to inherit the XAML, the XAMLs are different, it is the code behind that have common functionality. I have read a number of comments saying that I'm suppose to 1) have a base class that have no XAML and inherits UserControl and 2) a child that would have it's class and XAML inherit from the base class.

Comment: @HighCore: Further to the above, I have (before searching for an answer) inherited the base class in the child and leaving the XAML untouched and I get this error "Base class 'System.Windows.Controls.UserControl' specified for class 'Child1Class' cannot be different from the base class 'BaseClass' of one of its other partial types." This error is from both Child1Class.g.vb and Child1Class.g.i.vb.

Comment: @NotMe I did not say anything about "inheriting XAML". I said there is NO need to inherit XAML-based UIs, regardless of anything. If you're creating a `Custom Control` (which is doubtful), then you create a simple purely code-based class that inherits `Control` or even `FrameworkElement`. Chances are that you're trying to inherit functionality that should be put in a ViewModel instead. **Please edit your question and clarify why you're trying to do this. Chances are there is a much better approach that does not involve UI element inheritance**